# Tesseract confuses + (plus sign) with 4 in simple equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

How can I correct it? I already tried using lang="eng+equ" parameter to improve results to no avail.

```
  import cv2
  import pytesseract
  import numpy as np

  img = cv2.imread("image.png")
  img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1.2, fy=1.2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
  img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
  kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
  img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 1))
  img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
  content = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng+equ", config="--psm 13 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789+=")
  print(content)
```

This is the image: [image]

But Tesseract detects it as 424 + 26 =

Comment: There are many results if you go searching for, perhaps, _tesseract improve accuracy_ - what have you tried from those results?

Comment: I tried using some functions from cv2 to improve the image quality...  Grayscale,Threshold, Dilate, erode but I still don't have good results. I don't know if I have to train the model because the image seems very simple.

Comment: All the results for _tesseract improve accuracy_ are out there for you to try.

Comment: The functions that I specified in the above comment already were the results from my search to improve accuracy. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the entire image, or is that the subset to your image? If it's the latter, that may be your issue.

I've found that PyTess can provide different results depending on whether it's a whole, or the subset of an image.

Comment: It is the entire image!